# Ajax Jquery Popup While Page Open

Tags: jquery, ajax, popup

I want to add popup while page open. Like facebook like box or group sale site's email request popups while first load in page.

How can I add ajax-jquery popup box to web site while open web page first time?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI does this very easily

reference the ui script and css (they can be downloaded [Here](http://jqueryui.com/download/) if you don't have them already) after the core jQuery script like so:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Then the basic html for the popup window

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

And finally a little script to make it work:

```
 <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    });
    </script>
```

[Source](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default)

Comment: So, how can we ensure that to show just once in session or web site open?

Comment: Well, you'd probably want to issue a cookie with some property like "hideDialog" with a default value of 'false'.  After the page has loaded the first time, change the value to 'true'.  Then wrap the 'dialog' function above in an 'if' statement that checks the value of 'hideDialog' in the cookie before executing.